# ADB2C - Issue with 'SignIn only' user flow with MSAL library

Tags: aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

In my ADB2C application, I want to give only sign-In provision to user without sign-up option.

I am using ADB2C 'SignIn' user flow in .Net core application. I have included Microsoft identity in application. So, signin is taken care by this library by default.
When user click on 'SignIn' button by default MSAL(Microsoft identification library) consider 'SignUporSignIn' policy. If I add 'SignUporSignIn' user flow then it redirect to sign in page with sign up button, if I delete 'SignUporSignIn' user flow  then it return error page even though 'SignIn' user flow available.

Any idea how can I change this default behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MSAL config in your app, set the SignUporSignIn policy to b2c_1_signinonly.

Comment: I tried this earlier as well but not sure why it did not work but now its working. Thank you.